# R: Searching for specific arguments in a row

Tags: r, datatable

I have 2 data tables. One lets call it df1 only has 2 columns

```
column1|column2
3      | 4 
3      | 6 
5      | 4
```

and then I have a df2 which can have 4 or more columns and even more rows

```
column1|column2|column3|column4
NA      | 3     |   NA  | NA
NA      | 5     |   6   | NA
3       | NA    |   4   | 1
```

and I have to find everyplace where the combination of df1 are represented in df2. In the example I made it would be 1. Since the only combo is in the 3. row in column1 and column3. Also I can only data.table command. Which means I can't use for or if anywhere. I tried using apply

```
rowcheck<-function(df1, df2){
    apply(df1, 1, function(x) any(apply(df2, 1, function(y) all(y==x))))
}
```

and

```
(do.call(paste0, df1) %in% do.call(paste0, df2))
```

and many more but I just can't seem to get it. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

Comment: Are these actually `data.table` objects, or are they `data.frame` objects?

Comment: data.table objects

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(`column 1` = c(3,3,5), `column 2` = c(4,6,4))
df2 <- data.table(`column 1` = c(NA,NA,3), `column 2` = c(3,5,NA),`column 3` = c(NA,6,4),`column 4` = c(NA,NA,1))
```

First we want to find everyplace where the combination of df1 are represented in df2. We start with solving this for the first row of df1.

We start with getting the rows that contains the value of `df1$column 1[1]` for each column of `df2`. We consider all **NA** to be no matches at all.

```
 lapply(
   df2,
   function(column){
     !is.na(column) & 
      column == df1$`column 1`[1]}  )
```

here we are using the fact that data.tables are actually lists with each column being an element of this list.

we now have list of vectors containing the rows. We need to merge these together to one single vector for that we pipe our results with `%>%` in to a Reduce function and taking the logical **or** `|` of all vectors

```
 lapply(
   df2,
   function(column){
     !is.na(column) & 
     column == df1$`column 1`[idx]
   }) %>% Reduce(`|`,., init = FALSE)
```

We now have a vector with all the rows of `df2` that contains the value of `df1$column 1[1]` in any column. we do the same for `df1$column 2[1]` and taking the logical **and** `&`

```
lapply(
  df2,
  function(column){
    !is.na(column) & 
    column == df1$`column 1`[1]} 
) %>% 
  Reduce(|,., init = FALSE) & 
lapply(
  df2,
  function(column){
    !is.na(column) & 
     column == df1$`column 2[1]`} 
) %>% 
  Reduce(|,., init = FALSE))
```

To now answer our first question we just need to ask if their are **any** rows in `df2` containg the vaues of `df1`and transfer this to all the rows of `df1` with a call of sapply

```
   sapply(1:nrow(df1),function(idx){any(lapply(df2,function(column){!is.na(column) & column == df1$`column 1`[idx]}  ) %>% Reduce(`|`,., init = FALSE) & lapply(df2,function(column){!is.na(column) & column == df1$`column 2`[idx]}  ) %>% Reduce(`|`,., init = FALSE))})
```

To answer the secoind question (posted in the commests below) how many times each row is contained in `df2` we just need change the `anny` to `sum` using `mutate`and `filter` from the `dplyr` package we can get a nice table containing all the rows of `df1` in `df2` with their counts

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(count = sapply(1:nrow(df1),function(idx){sum(lapply(df2,function(column){!is.na(column) & column == df1$`column 1`[idx]}  ) %>% Reduce(`|`,., init = FALSE) & lapply(df2,function(column){!is.na(column) & column == df1$`column 2`[idx]}  ) %>% Reduce(`|`,., init = FALSE))})) %>% 
  filter(count > 0)
  column 1 column 2 count
1        3        4     1
```

Comment: I will explain the code later when I have a bit more time ;-)

Comment: It didn't work at first it said that the function %>% did not exist so I removed the %. After that it said "Error in Reduce(`|`, ., init = FALSE) : object '.' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e2) :".

Comment: Sorry I am using the package dplyr `%>%` is part of this package

Comment: Aaaah okay, I see now, however your code show every place in df1 that is used, however I need to see in df2 where it is used. that way I could count how many different places the combos are in. for example if I had 4th row in df2 where there is also a combo of 3 and 4 from df1(row1) then it would only return that and I couldn't count how  many times there were combos.

Comment: To get the number of hits replace the any with sum.    Then of course you can't use it to get the rows of df1

Comment: Hi John, I have updated my example with a description of my code and extended it to count the number of hits for each row.